# Passing date.getTime through activities, using date.setTime in the destination activity, getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, date

I want to send a certain date.getTime() through activities, and then set it in the destination activity date.setTime(). Here is my code:

Sending activity:

```
[...]

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                    Intent i = new Intent(RecentSightings.this,
                        AlertViewOnMap.class);
                    // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                    i.putExtra("createdAt", alertsList.get(position).getCreatedAt().getTime());

                    startActivity(i);

                }


            });

[...]
```

And this is the receiving activity:

```
package com.fourbox.bocterapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlertViewOnMap extends Activity {

    public Date alertTime;

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(com.fourbox.bocterapp.R.layout.details_design);

    alertTime.setTime(getIntent().getLongExtra("createdAt", 0));

[...]
```

I have checked with the debugger, and the sending activity sends the long variable(miliseconds) right, but when it reaches "alertTime.setTime([...])", i get the following error:

> > FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity >>ComponentInfo{com.fourbox.bocterapp/com.fourbox.bocterapp.AlertViewOnMap}: >>java.lang.NullPointerException

I am having problems in realising what I am doing wrong. Could you help me?

With respects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the alertTime variable in the receiving activity.
    public Date alertTime = new Date();

Comment: @user3641244 If this answer solves your question, then click the empty checkmark to turn it green and formally accept this answer.